# Changing Windows firewall rules with PowerShell (Open / Close a specific port)

Tags: windows, powershell, firewall

I'm doing some end to end testing of an application and I need to be able to close then open a port in Windows Firewall using PowerShell commands. I've found a script that adds a firewall rule to open a port, but I also need to be able to close the port.

Script to open -

```
 $port = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.FWOpenPort
 $port.Port = 9999
 $port.Name = 'MyTestPort'
 $port.Enabled = $true

 $fwMgr = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.FwMgr
 $profile = $fwMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile
 $profile.GloballyOpenPorts.Add($port)
```

Is it possible to close the port in similar fashion? What would the commands looks like?  I've tried using the .Remove but can't seem to get it working, unless it doesn't apply to Windows 7.

Hopefully the commands will work on Windows 7 (for testing locally), and Server 2008 and up.

Comment: What OS version are you on?  if it's 2012/win 8 type help *firewall*, there are a ton of cmdlets for it.

Comment: I'm developing locally under Windows 7. The automation server is Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the rule. Change this one line:

```
$port.Enabled = $true
```

to this:

```
$port.Enabled = $false
```

The rule will be disabled instead of enabled.

Tested in Windows Server 2012 R2 and seems to work fine.